# remove second quotes from text regexp_substs

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below text:

```
 PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TFSE"."PRODUCT_C": invalid identifier
```

I want to get the value PRODUCT_C, but I am getting TFSE instead

this is my query, usually the text was`ora-00904 PRODUCT_C` so the below was working.

```
select  regexp_substr('PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TFSE"."PRODUCT_C": invalid identifier', '[^"]+', 1, 2) from dual
```

edit:

sometime my message will be like this

`PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PRODUCT_C": invalid identifier`
or like this

`PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TFSE"."PRODUCT_C": invalid identifier`

how can i adjust the regex_substr in a way to have result `

`PRODUCT_C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, but no cigar, eh?

```
SQL> select  regexp_substr('PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TFSE"."PRODUCT_C": invalid identifier', '[^"]+', 1, 4) from dual;

REGEXP_SU
---------
PRODUCT_C
```

**[EDIT, after reading the comment]**

```
SQL> with test as (select 'PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PRODUCT_C": invalid identifier' col from dual union
  2                select 'PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TFSE"."PRODUCT_C": invalid identifier' from dual
  3               )
  4  select col,
  5    regexp_substr(col, '[^"]+', 1, regexp_count(col, '"')) result
  6  from test;

COL                                                       RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------- ---------------
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PRODUCT_C": invalid identifier        PRODUCT_C
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TFSE"."PRODUCT_C": invalid identifier PRODUCT_C

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response , i edit my question can you check it please , is there a trick for it ?

Comment: @Moudiz . . . It is rude to change a question after it has been answered, because it can invalidate an existing answer (as your change does).  I think it is better to ask another question.  This answers your original question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff well my question was not explained good , ill post another no problem

Comment: This relies on the last pattern delimited by double quotes.In my opinion, a  bettersolution would be to extract the 3rd parameter between colons (standard oracle error message ) and then the last between quotes

Comment: Yes, it relies on sample input data. As usual, there are several ways to get the result. Feel free to post another one(s), if you wish.

Comment: @KaushikNayak if you have another way please share it.

Comment: @Moudiz : Sure, give me some time .

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to first extract the third pattern separated by a colon and then search for the last pattern between the double quotes.

This adds another layer of check to ensure that you are picking the right element out of the error message before extracting the quoted string.

```
SELECT
   regexp_substr( regexp_substr ( s, '[^:]+', 1, 3) , '"([^"]+)"$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) v 
FROM
   yourtable t
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/572)